# Android Development: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.bf

Tags: android, android-service, google-play-services, unbind, mapfragment

I'm using the "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" to display a map in a embedded fragment. When I try to close the activity (or wait a few seconds), the application crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.bf@5368ecf4
            at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:921)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1459)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:484)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.c.a(SourceFile:145)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.bc.handleMessage(SourceFile:208)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I even tried to start the map fragment with a try/catch:

```
try {
            GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
            options.zoomControlsEnabled(true);

            mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(options);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(application.DEBUG_STRING, "error: ", e);
        }
```

and

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        try {
            if (longitude > 0 && latitude > 0) {
                markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();

                MarkerOptions parkingPosition = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title(getString(R.string.positionOfCar));

                googleMap.addMarker(parkingPosition);
                markers.add(parkingPosition);

                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                for (MarkerOptions marker : markers) {
                    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
                }
                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

                int padding = 10; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);


//            googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
//            googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bounds.getCenter(), 10));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

                Log.d(application.DEBUG_STRING, "zoom " + googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);

                if (googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom >= 18) {
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(application.DEBUG_STRING, "error: ", e);
        }
    }
```

Has anyone an idea to fix the problem?

Comment: Hi Evid. Have you figured out what was the cause? Having the same issue.

Comment: you may want to try    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();   options .useViewLifecycleInFragment(true)  method  reference https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions#useViewLifecycleInFragment(boolean)